# Fatal error Uncaught exception Exception with message SSL certificate unable to get local issuer certificate in using Unirest api in NetBean

Tags: php

I am simply using mashape api with php 5.6 then am getting error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SSL certificate
 problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in

```
$response =    
Unirest\Request::get("https://indianpost.p.mashape.com/getPincodes.php? 
name=delhi",
                array(
                     "X-Mashape-Key" => "mykey",
                     "Accept" => "application/json"
                    )
                );

    echo "Successfully";
```

How can i solve it.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I am not getting anything what i try.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
Unirest\Request::verifyPeer(false);
```

Comment: Thanks i also stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is correct way but for now workaround 
In Request.php replace CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER =>self::$verifyPeer with
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false